# Local image in canvas in chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, canvas, local

chrome's access to local files are restricted, but I would like to draw an image on a canvas: an image selected with a file input and without sending the image to the server and then requesting it back.

Some help would be great!

Comment: Is your HTML file also local, or are you asking the user to go to your website, select a file from disk, and then have JavaScript access to that file without ever sending it to your server?

Comment: Second answer. The purpose is to make modifications on the image, and upload to the server seems to be time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your using Google Chrome, file:// URIs cannot read other file:// URIs. If you are using this for development, then you can add the following command line switch to chrome:

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

HTML5 has (currently in development) [FileSystem API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/) you can read an example from it here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not on the local domain, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript).